# Show that P(x_k) → P(x)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $P(x) = (a_n)x^n + (a_{n-1})x^{n-1} +...+(a_1)x + (a_0)$ be a polynomial. ($a_i$ are constants and $a_n ≠ 0$). Assume the sequence $x_k → x$ when $k → ∞$, Show that $P(x_k) → P(x)$

Answer (score 1):

What do you know about the convergence of $a x_k$ for any real number $a$ and $x_k^m$ for any natural number $m$? What do you know about products and sums of convergent sequences?
Another formulation of your problem is: Show that $P$ as a function is continuous at $x$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is right, but here we go...

First |x^i - (x_k)^i| = |x - x_k||x^(i-1) + x^(i-2)x_k + x^(i-3)(x_k)^2 + ...+(x_k)^(i-1)| for all i. For k large |x_k| < 2|x| ==> |x^i - (x_k)^i| <= |x - x_k|{2^(i-1)i|x|^(i-1)}.

Write M = max{(a_i)i2^(i-1)|x|^(i-1)} for all i. Then |P(x) - P(x_k)| <= M |x - x_k| --> 0 as k --> ∞